Which STM32F405RGT6 pins are suitable for PWM?
I plan to connect three 9g servos to the STM32F405RGT6 (datasheet) and need to select the appropriate GPIO pins for PWM output. Can I use pins PA8, PA9, and PA10 for this purpose, as these pins are associated with TIM1_CH1, TIM1_CH2, and TIM1_CH3?

Maybe. You could verify from the reference manual or configure the PWM outputs in CubeMX to be sure.

Picture below shows timer1 pin configuration in STM32CubeMX for STM32F405RGT
you can also use other timers for this purpose.

